# How can you damage DMM if you haven't discharged a capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, multimeter, damage

**Hi, I measured capacitance on some capacitors** using my UNI-T 139S True RMS Multimeter **without discharging them first**. To be clear, I don't even know if they were charged because they are mounted on the PCB in USB charger that I disassembled (I disconnected it from the socket and after 1 hour I began disassebling it). Later I read in multimeter instructions that you should discharge capacitors first. In instructions that I got with it, in the Capacitance measurement section it says that the **multimeter has overload protection: 600V-PTC**.

**I am wondering what damage it can cause to a multimeter ?** *Capacitor values that I measured are below.*

USB Charger:
90 -260 VAC 50-60Hz

Capacitor values:
470μF 10V,
4.7μF 400V

*UNI-T 139S safety standards:* [UT139S](https://www.uni-trend.com/uploadfile/2018/1129/20181129032713354.pdf)

Comment: What measurements were you performing to the charged capacitors? Voltage measurements or something else?

Comment: Your DMM probably short circuited depending on what  you were trying to measure.

Comment: I was measuring capacitance. On the dial, it is together with resistance, diode test and continuity test. Probes were plugged correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can you damage DMM if you haven't discharged a capacitor?

Most multimeters test capacitance in one of two ways:

- Injecting a small AC signal into the capacitor and measuring what happens, and/or
- Paralelling an inductor, giving it an electronic "kick", and measuring the oscillating frequency. Calculation from the reference inductor value = capacitance value.

Both of these require small signals and small voltages. Applying large voltages to this can damage components. All meters are different, so consult the documentation of yours for any relevant information. Most manufacturers are void of operating details. But violating the limitations of the meter can indeed result in temporary or permanent damage. Typically a traditional glass or ceramic fuse will fail, preventing all operation. Usually these are accessible by removing the battery door, or on some models, the outer enclosure.

Measuring capacitance is more complicated than other modes because reference components may need to be switched in/out, or the meter may need to sample and electrically "kick" the capacitor, etc.

> Multimeter has overload protection: 600V-PTC.

Some dedicated capacitor testers simply use diodes back-to-back across the terminals for protection, which effectively limit the usable signal to +/-0.6v and anything over this is shorted. I've heard of at least one other meter which keeps relay contacts closed across the terminals, until the "test" button is pressed. And both of these were damaged by connecting charged caps - a diode was welded shorted on the first, and relay contact welded closed on the second.

Your particular meter apparently uses at least a [600v positive-temperature-coefficient reset-able fuse](https://www.littelfuse.com/products/resettable-ptcs.aspx), likely with other components such as clamping diodes, to reduce the chances of high voltages damaging it while in capacitance mode. This "polyfuse" is designed to "open" as it gets warm, disallowing further current to flow. After it cools it should work again.  This is more convenient than a traditional fuse in that it doesn't need replacing and can be reused several times. However heating is slow, and if heated too quickly or too severely (by say, a large capacitor charged to a high voltage) it may never return to a functional status. Traditional fuses can be much faster-acting so would be preferred for this role. So in that sense, a polyfuse would not be my first choice for a capacitance testing mode, because it may let in too much current before it warms enough to open.

So to answer "how can the meter be damaged if the capacitor is not discharged", the capacitor itself could be damaged due to high currents, a fuse could be damaged if so equipped, protection diodes could permanently short, reference inductors could be vaporized, and/or other parts of the meter including [D2A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital-to-analog_converter) and [A2D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog-to-digital_converter) converters, even the CPU itself, rendering repair impossible.

**Make it a habit - discharge all capacitors before testing (even little ones.)**

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can I check the internal components for damage? Are there any noticeable signs of damage that I should be aware of? Btw after your answer, I disassembled another piece of equipment that I have and I measured capacitance on some capacitors(I have discharged them with screwdriver) and the values that DMM measured were very similar to the values written on the capacitors (for example 22μF 400V is displayed as 21.53μF).

Comment: I also tested some resistors. All readings are accurate.

Comment: Disassembled one more piece of equipment. I have measured capacitance on some capacitors (discharged them with screwdriver). Readings are also accurate and correct. Should I consider my multimeter as not damaged if the readings are accurate?

Comment: Well it sounds as if your meter is functioning normally, at least for the ranges of capacitance tested.  If it can display decade capacitance values correctly (such as 0.001µF (1nF), 0.01µF (10nF), 0.1µF (100nF), 1.0µF, 10µF etc) then chances are it is fine and usable. Note that there is more to capacitors than just their capacitance; and there is a whole other class of testers for just testing [ESR](https://xtronics.com/wiki/Capacitors_and_ESR.html) or *equivalent-series-resistance*. [Mr. Carlson's Lab](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lLQThhf3Brc) has a video about testing capacitors.

Comment: I don't have a capacitor with decade capacitance. Also those 2 capacitors that I haven't checked if they were charged were on USB charger board and I read somewhere on the internet that those capacitors are used to stabilize voltage and that they discharge almost immediately after disconnected from the socket (I left that charger on the table for one hour, went on coffee, and then I began disassembling it). So I am interested in your final conclusion. What are the odds that those capacitors damaged internal components, and what are the noticable signs of damage that I can check?

Comment: They might discharge quickly; the only way to know for sure would be to measure voltage across them before testing. Noticeable signs of damage would be burned or broken components, along with the inability to measure capacitance of some range at least. Since you seem to be able to measure several different capacitors, the meter is likely fine. You still may want to find and test say a 10nF and 10,000uF cap to make sure all ranges are working correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have found 1000µF capacitor. Meter is displaying it as 1.091 mF. Meter RANGE: 99.99nf ~ 999.9µF RESOLUTION: 0.01nF ~ 0.1µF ACCURACY: +- (4% + 5).........................RANGE: 9.999mF ~ 99.99mF RESOLUTION: 0.001mF ~ 0.01mF ACCURACY: +-10%

Answer (score 0):

The multimeter says CAT III 600V for the capacitance measurements, however, usually capacitance measurements on a meter injects charge and then measures the response (sometimes a frequency and then measured response). Either way these are sensitive measurements and probably use different circuitry than the voltage measurement and are not equipped to handle high voltage.

In the manual it specifically states to not use the capacitance measurement while powered or charged:

> - Switch off the power supply to the circuit and fully discharge all capacitors
> - Before measuring capacitors (especially for high voltage capacitors), please fully discharge them

Odds are you have damaged the meter because the instructions were not followed. It's kind of misleading to say you can put 600V on the probes on the outside of the meter, but the manual shows that its a bad idea. They should put a voltage range on the capacitance measurements. Always follow the manual.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How big are those odds? Both capacitors were rated 400V and the limit is 600V.